# List or scalar context when returning an array or list with a single element

Tags: perl

I have a function `func` that can return a single value or a list of values, depending on how the function is called. So for this particular function,  the caller would know when to expect only a single return value, and therefore would like to use the simpler syntax `my $var = func( ... )` instead of `my ($var) = func( ... )`. The problem is that in some cases the single value is converted into the size of a list/array with one element, and in some cases not. For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

for (1..4) {
    no strict 'refs';
    my $a = &{"func".$_}();
    say $a;
}

sub func1 {
    return ("Hi");
}

sub func2 {
    my @a = ("Hi");
    return @a;
}

sub func3 {
    my @a = ("Hi");
    return (@a);
}

sub func4 {
    my @a = ("Hi");
    return (pop @a);
}
```

Gives output:

```
Hi
1
1
Hi
```

Why do I get a 1 in some cases and `"Hi"` in other cases?

Comment: In the two middle cases, you are returning an *array*. Standard behavior for an array in a scalar context is to return the number of elements. `"Hi"` is a scalar, and so is `pop`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return expression is evaluated in the same context as the function itself. [Here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=347416)'s a pretty comprehensive list of what returns what in scalar context.

As it applies here:

- `func1`: String literals don't care about context. `"Hi"` evaluates to the string `Hi`, so `func1` returns `Hi`.
- `func2`: In scalar context, `@a` evaluates to the number of elements in `@a`, so `func2` returns `1`.
- `func3`: In scalar context, `@a` evaluates to the number of elements in `@a`, so `func3` returns `1`.
- `func4`: `pop` doesn't care about context. `pop(@a)` evaluates to the removed element (or undef if `@a` was empty), so `func4` returns `Hi`.

Note that parentheses just override precedence, which has no effect in any of your examples.

You want

```
sub func {
   my @a = ...;
   return wantarray ? @a : $a[-1];
}
```

If you want to be clever, you could also use the following, since a slice in scalar context returns the last element if would have returned in list context:

```
sub func {
   my @a = ...;
   return @a[0..$#a];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I understand it better now.. You do not create a list until a comma is given. So `("Hi")` is not a list, but `("Hi", "I")` is a list?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, "List" is a pretty generic word. In the pilcrow's quote, "list" refers to the list operator, also known as the comma operator. So `"Hi"` isn't a list, but `"Hi", "I"` is. (Parens just change precedence.)  // List also commonly refers to what a sub or function returns. It simply means "some number of scalars". // In list context, the list/comma operator `"Hi", "I"` returns a list consisting of two scalars. Like all other operators, the list/comma operator `"Hi", "I"` returns a single scalar in scalar context.

Comment: s/returns a list consisting of two scalars\K/ (which is a fancy way of saying it returns two scalars)/

Answer (score 2):

From [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values):

> If you evaluate an array in scalar context, it returns the length of the array. (Note that this is not true of lists, which return the last value, like the C comma operator, nor of built-in functions, which return whatever they feel like returning.)

Sometimes you return the result of an array in scalar context (`func2`, `func3`), sometimes the result of a string literal in scalar context (`func1`) and sometimes the result of `pop` in scalar context (`func4`).  Hence the difference.

Comment: Thanks, this was probably the point I missed, that is: lists return the last value (a scalar) and therefore behaves differently than arrays.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, But you didn't use any lists in your question? Anyway, what you want is [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=347416). Added to me answer.

Comment: Also note that the quote is a little inaccurate. Lists in scalar context don't evaluate return the last value (it would have returned in list context); lists in scalar context return the last item of the list evaluated in scalar context. `perl -E'@a=qw(x y); say @a,@a; say scalar(@a,@a)'`.