# Convert array to list

Tags: perl

```
sub get_list {
    return ("one", "two");
}

sub get_array {
    my @a = ("one", "two");

    # need to convert @a to list
    return @a;
}

my $two = get_list(); # desired, assigns last item in list to scalar 
my $count = get_array(); # evaluates array in scalar context, returning a count
```

In the get_array() method, I already have an array created, but I want to return it as a list so that it assigns according to list rules and not array rules. The array of course would normally be built in a more complex way (not directly from a list).

I have tried using map in hopes that it would return me a list of values, but this gives the same results. Same with split/join.

```
return map { $_ } @a;
return split /,/, join(",", @a);
```

How can I convert the array into a list of values?

Comment: You have some sever misunderstandings about how things work. Both `get_array` and `get_list` return a list (a number of scalars) in list context and a single scalar in scalar context.

Comment: I understand they both return scalars in scalar context, but the string "two" and an integer representing the number of items in the array are completely different results even though both are scalars.

Comment: I know. It's "I want to return it as a list so that it assigns according to list rules and not array rules" that makes no sense.

Comment: See [List or scalar context when returning an array or list with a single element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32051534/176646). (The answer still applies even though you have more than one element in your list and array.)

Comment: Assigning a list to a scalar assigns the last item of the list. Assigning an array counts the array and assigns the count. This is what I mean by list rules vs array rules. Whatever you call it, the results are different if the value is a 'list' vs an 'array'. I already have an array but I want to return it as a 'list of values' so that the list behavior (assigning the last element) is applied instead of the array behavior (counting). Sorry, but I showed this clearly with a few lines of code and I don't know how to make that any more clear.

Comment: Re "I already have an array but I want to return it as a 'list of values'" Again, that makes no sense. You can only return a scalar in scalar context. /// Re "I showed this clearly with a few lines of code and I don't know how to make that any more clear", I didn't say I had any problems understanding what you wanted.

Comment: @ikegami, The persub docs state that a sub returns a flat list of scalars.  What does the flat list returned by the get_array() sub look like?  Is it a flat list containing an internal reference to the array, which when it finds itself in scalar context produces the length of the array?  It can't be a flat list containing a *real* perl reference because we can return a perl reference ourselves, which produces a different result, right?

Comment: @7stud, When called in list context, `get_array` returns two scalars with respective values of `'one'` and `'two'`. When called in scalar context, it returns one scalar with a value of `2`. // When called in list context, `get_list` returns two scalars with respective values of `'one'` and `'two'`. When called in scalar context, it returns one scalar with a value of `'two'`.

Comment: Note: There's no difference between saying "returns a list of two scalars" and saying "returns two scalars". "flat" is similarly a fluff word.

Comment: @ikegami, Okay, that makes sense: the wantarray result is determined before the return value is constructed.  And lists and arrays respond differently to not wantarray.

Comment: @7stud, Right. Every operator that can return something other than a single scalar has to use the internal equivalent of `wantarray` (called `GIMME`) to determine whether it is required to return a single scalar or not. Context is not applied after the fact, but determines what it returned in the first place.

Comment: For the op, the translation of the previous comments is: perl does an ***implicit*** wantarray check before each of your subs return.  And when the context does not want-an-array, i.e. scalar context, lists and arrays produce different results.

Comment: @ikegami, lol.  Why does Wumpus Q. Wumbley's answer not do the implicit wantarray check before returning?

Comment: @7stud, What makes you think it doesn't? [code](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/0ab152a1d10861997fe3e1b985cc92f142f4cec7:/pp.c#l4596) PS - I posted that solution before WQW. (See the link ThisSuitIsBlackNot posted above).

Comment: @7stud [Slices in scalar context return the last item of the slice.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)

Comment: [Arrays vs. Lists](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer with `wantarray` makes the intent explicit, which is good. But if you want something that looks more like magic which you can refer to as "listifying the array" to confuse and impress people, a slice will do it:

```
return @a[0..$#a];
```

Answer (score 5):

Functions can use [wantarray](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html) to determine the context they're in and return something accordingly:

```
sub get_array {
    my @a = ("one", "two");
    return wantarray ? @a : $a[-1];
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution and certainly works when it comes to scalar assignment. Would there be any other situation though where the array would behave differently than if a list was returned?

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  The long and the short of my solution is: If `get_array` is called in list context, the elements `"one"` and `"two"` of the array will be returned.  If it's called in scalar context, the final element of the array will be returned.  Can you elaborate some other hypothetical situation than these two?

Answer (score 0):

Curiously, the answers focused on the stuff in the subroutine instead of giving you the proper answer. If you want list behavior, do list operations. Perl largely decides how to treat things based on what you are doing, so be comfortable telling Perl how to treat data rather than relying on tricks to make it work out.

In your case, assign to a list:

```
my( $item ) = get_list(); 
my( $item ) = get_array();
```

Those both return the first item because there is only one variable on the lefthand side and the lefthand list simply ignores the remaining items from the righthand list.

If you wanted the second item but not the first or third, you can use `undef` as a placeholder:

```
my( undef, $item ) = get_list();
```

I hardly ever do that because a slice is easier:

```
my $item = (get_list())[1];
```

If you want the last items, take a list slice and count backward from the end with a negative subscript:

```
my $item = (get_list())[-1]; 
my $item = (get_array())[-1];
```

And, if you are the one creating those subroutines and you only want the last item in the list, don't return a list at all. Simply return the value you want. You'll notice that Perl does this for many of its builtin functions (`localtime`, `get*`, and so on).

Here are some more examples:

```
use v5.10;

my( undef, undef, $mode ) = stat('/etc/hosts');
printf "mode is %o\n", $mode;

say "Hour is ", (localtime)[2];

say "User is " . getpwuid(501); # concatenation, so scalar context
my $name = getpwuid(501); # scalar assignment, so scalar context
say "User is $name";

my $uid = (getpwnam($name))[2];
say "UID is $uid";
```

Answer (score -1):

See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) `comma operator`:

> Binary "," is the comma operator. In scalar context it evaluates its
>   left argument, throws that value away, then evaluates its right
>   argument and returns that value. This is just like C's comma operator.

And see [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors) `list value constructors`:

> In a context not requiring a list value, the value of what appears to
>   be a list literal is simply the value of the final element, as with
>   the C comma operator. For example,
>
> ```
> @foo = ('cc', '-E', $bar);
> ```
>
> assigns the entire list value to array @foo, but
>
> ```
> $foo = ('cc', '-E', $bar);
> ```
>
> assigns the value of variable $bar to the scalar variable $foo. Note
>   that the value of an actual array in scalar context is the length of
>   the array;

From the [map docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html):

> map EXPR,LIST
>
> Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each element of LIST (locally setting
>   $_ to each element) and ***returns the list value*** composed of the results
>   of each such evaluation.

Perfect!  Just what you want:

```
my @arr = ('a', 'b', 'c');

my $result = map "-->$_<--", @arr;
say $result; #=>3  ???
```

Boo, hoo:

> In scalar context, [map] returns the total number of elements so generated.

So, after reading Sean's answer you can surmise that `map()` is defined to do the equivalent of the following:

```
 return wantarray ? (result1, result2,...,resultN) : N;
```

Same thing for [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> Splits the string EXPR into a list of strings and returns the list in
>   list context, or the size of the list in scalar context.

Answer (score -2):

I needed a list of variables. Maybe somebody else needs that, too:

```
my $start = 0;
my $length = 10;
my $database = "foo";
my $chapter = "bar";
my @sql_wheres = ();
push(@sql_wheres, "database LIKE ?") if ($database);
push(@sql_wheres, "chapter LIKE ?") if ($chapter);

# more code here to use DBI and initilize $select

$select->execute( (@wheres), $start, $length );
```

Without the round brackets around (@wheres) it did not work. But with the round brackets the variables where supplied as a list.

Comment: These return the same thing in scalar context. Since there's no comma operator in the `get_list`, there's no chance for the comma operator to be in scalar context.

Comment: Did you try it out? I used it in $select->execute( (@wheres), $start, $length ); Without the round brackets it did not work, but with the brackets it worked.

Comment: I tried the example you posted. It does not work. I suspect something else is going on in your second code example, which has no context and uses undeclared variables. Perhaps there was something else going on with your second example. But, you can't generalize from your second example to your first.

Comment: Okay, I edited the answer down to what I used. Maybe somebody else can use it , too.