# Cast array into list

Tags: perl

I have a file that I need to read into a list so I can use it in [Template Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_List_References). I can do that easy with array and I am bit struggling with list. Is there a way to cast array into list?

```
# file.txt
foo
bar
zoo
```

```
my $filename = shift;
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp $row;
  unshift @yy_array, $row;
}

my $zz_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'zoo'];

say "### Dumper - array ###";
print Dumper \@yy_array;
say "### Dumper - list ###";
print Dumper $zz_list;

### Dumper - array ###
$VAR1 = [
          'zoo',
          'bar',
          'foo'
        ];
### Dumper - list ###
$VAR1 = [
          'foo',
          'bar',
          'zoo'
        ];
###
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand.  The file gets read, line by line, and you store those lines in the array `@yy_array` (in reverse order).  What do you need to do with that? (Btw, what you call a "list", `[...]`, is an  array reference.)

Comment: I need to refer it in the template toolkit and it accept only a list:

http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_List_References

Comment: OK.  I last looked at that years ago, let me see...

Comment: Thanks! I looked a number of question but I am unsure if there is a "simple" way

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685788/convert-array-to-list

Comment: Right, the Template::Toolkit's "list" is  an array reference... and you got an answer :)

Comment: Template Toolkit's documentation uses incorrect terminology. It wants a *reference to an array* (aka *array reference*). There's no such thing as a *reference to a list* (or *list reference*) since *list* isn't a type of variable in Perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you call a list is an array reference. You can use the reference operator to get a reference to an array:

```
my $array_ref = \@array;
```

Another option is to create a new anonymous array and populate it by the elements of the array:

```
my $array_ref = [@array];
```

To get the array back from the reference, you dereference:

```
my @arr2 = @{ $array_ref };
```

Comment: Thats it! I tried join/split/cat but I got a number instead.

I understand what is an array reference (well, I guess not), the ARRAY(0x1246). Do you mind elaborate how this work internally?

Comment: See [perlref](https://perldoc.pl/perlref) and [perlreftut](https://perldoc.pl/perlreftut). Also, updated with a dereference example.